# How to fix Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest' in React Native?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradle, android-manifest

I find an error when run the project, I try to look for many examples but fail all, this is the detail of error:

```
D:\myApp\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
```

Please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some more libraries(other than deviceinfo) that depended on gcm so I used this to fix the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56648987/8306924

Answer (score 8):

So I faced this issue while installing `react-native-reanimated` in order to make `react-navigation-drawer` working.

The fix was:

1. Add to android/gradle.properties:

```java
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

2. `yarn add jetifier`
3. In android directory run:
   `./gradlew clean`
4. Run:
   `yarn jetify`
5. `react-native run-android`

My RN version 0.59.8

Comment: doesn't work for me been stuck on this for 2 days keeps showing >                                     
Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Comment: Maybe something changed since then...

Comment: setting the build tools version in build.gradle file to buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1" worked for me

Comment: Jetifier is deprecated now

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading 'react-native-device-info' to version 2.1.2 fixed the error for me.
See http://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25294#issuecomment-503024749

Answer (score 3):

finally found a solution after 2days and just added below two lines to android/build.gradle

googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"

firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"

Comment: where in the file would these go?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to edit "gradle.properties" and add:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

So you resolved the dependency conflicts between google and third party dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I downgraded java version from `17` to `15` and it works

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue and changed version of gradle on android > build.gradle and fixed my problem

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
```

to

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1")
```

clean gradle and build again

in android directory command prompt:

```
#gradlew clean
#gradlew build
```

Comment: after then, upgrade JAVA to 11 maybe help you go next:
```bash
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask zulu11
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the Execution failed for task :app:processDebugMainManifest’ in React Native Android project for JDK 16, 17, and above is to add the following line in the ./android/gradle.properties file in your project:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED