# Build failed with an exception react native

Tags: android, react-native

while running react-native run-android I am getting below exception...
It was running fine and I made a `git pull` and did npm ci and after that, it is coming. There are no changes in the new pull also. In fact for after doing git colon that is also the same issue.
And it's running well in MAC.
Please help I am stuck.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-33:19 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
128 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 125 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this

```
npm uninstall react-native-device-info
```

and then

```
npm install --save react-native-device-info
```

latest version should be  2.1.2

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your app/build.gradle dependencies:

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
            force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
            force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    }
}
```

This basically forces your third party libraries(like deviceinfo) that depend on gcm, to use the 16.1.0 version.

Comment: Thank you mate, it temporarly fixes the problem. But the definitive solution will be to switch to RN 0.60+ and androidX: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23112

Comment: I am not using any of these dependencies

Comment: @AbhigyanGaurav I wasn't using a couple of them either but it built for me with these, try it out once

Comment: @Żabojad yes this is a temporary fix- forcing a library version isn't ideal anyway.

Comment: Updating the react-native-device-info will also work
yarn upgrade react-native-device-info@2.1.2

Comment: @AnshuKumar yes that works if device info is the only library you're using that has a dependency on gcm, however like in our case we had multiple libraries that had that dependency(and unlike deviceinfo, all hadn't updated their libraries to comply with gcm's new version), so we temporarily rolled back the gcm version itself.